# Shorter syntax for filter chaining

Tags: c#, linq

```
var fileIO = new FileIO();
var datafiles = _fileIo.GetFileDetails(directory)
   .Where(f => !f.FileName.EndsWith(".csv"))
   .Where(f => !f.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
   .Where(f => !f.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"));
```

Seems there should be a more succinct syntax that allows passing a list of suffix strings.

Answer (score 11):

What about this?:

```
var fileExtensions = new HashSet<string>() { ".csv", ".xls", ".xlsx" };
var datafiles = _fileIo.GetFileDetails(directory)
                    .Where(f => 
fileExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f)));
```

We use `Path.GetExtension` to get ".csv" from "test.csv", and then compare that to a set of strings.

At the moment this comparison is case sensitive: `.csv` will match, but `.cSv` won't. You can add a `StringComparer` to handle this case insensitively:

```
var fileExtensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { ".csv", ".xls", ".xlsx" };
```

Comment: With `HashSet` you can add `HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` so it will also handle ".CsV" and all other variations.